# JavaScript Related Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My **Validation.js** file now 15000 lines but now I think set all validation function in individual page for better performance because when master page load then Whole **Validation.js** load and it takes time for loading. Give me proper way for set my **Validation.js** is proper or individual page wise set is proper?

Comment: If your .js file is external, it's already the most efficient.  Most browsers should cache the file, and therefore not need to load it from the server each time your page is served from IIS.  Putting it into a processed ASP.NET page will make it a lot worse

Comment: if you can't make page-level implementation to your js file .. try to `minify` it..that would save some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all your JavaScript code in the master page is definitely the worst idea unless all your pages do the same thing. Use specific file for specific needs will improve the performance. As to reusability concerns, you may want to use nested master pages so same kind of pages can share the same master page.

To validate input, you may consider using HTML5 validations if your customers use modern browsers. Then no (or at least less) JavaScript is required.

Comment: means individual page wise set is proper way

Comment: No. But make smaller files and combine some of them when necessary. Your validation script is larger than jQuery, a framework. In the real world, normal customers won't visit all your pages but maybe just one or two of them. Just feed them what is really needed. This could be more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two solutions here.

First you should minify your validation.js so all white spaces will get removed and the code will be trimed enough. You can use any third party utility (available Free online) which can trim the javascript and minify the variable names, declarations, arguments which really reduce the size by 50%

Secondly make a habbit to use it on the page where you really need it.
to do so you can either mannualy add the validation file or you can just create a nested master page and use that master page for your form pages. 
Hope this will help "_